# Textboxes in new window do not update when properties change in its datacontext

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I have several windows whose `datacontext` is set to a particular item in a collection from the `ItemsSource` of an `ItemsControl`. These windows contain textboxes which try to bind to different properties in the `datacontext`. However, even though I'm watching the values themselves update, the textboxes do not reflect any changes.

Here's my `ItemsControl` which is inside my MainWindow.xaml. The `ItemsSource` is a collection of `VehicleModel.cs` which I will post below.

```
<Window>
  </Grid>
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding VehicleCollection}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <Button Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}},
                                              Path=DataContext.ShowTimeWindowCmd}">
                        <Button.CommandParameter>
                            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource converter}">
                                <Binding Path="NowTime" />
                                <Binding />
                                <Binding Path="Name" />
                            </MultiBinding>
                        </Button.CommandParameter>
                    </Button>
                </Grid>
            </DateTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
 </Grid>
</Window>
```

Here are the models that hold the data.

```
public class VehicleModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private List<double> _nowTime = new List<double>();
    public List<double> NowTime
    {
        get { return _nowTime; }
        set { _nowTime = value; OnPropertyChanged("Nowtime"); }
    }

    private int _currentIteration;
    public int CurrentIteration //used to hold current index of the list of data fields
    {
        get { return _currentIteration; }
        set
        {
            _currentIteration = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("CurrentIteration");
            OnPropertyChanged("CurrentTime");
        }
    }

    private DateTime _firstTime; //holds the first record time in the ramp file
    public DateTime FirstTime
    {
        get { return _firstTime; }
        set { _firstTime = value; OnPropertyChanged("FirstTime"); }
    }

    private DateTime _lastTime; //holds the last record time in the ramp file
    public DateTime LastTime
    {
        get { return _lastTime; }
        set { _lastTime = value; OnPropertyChanged("LastTime"); }
    }

    public DateTime CurrentTime
    {
        get { return DateTime.FromOADate(NowTime[CurrentIteration]); }
        set
        {
            if ((value < FirstTime) || (value > LastTime))
            {
                CurrentTime = FirstTime;
            }
            else
            {
                NowTime[CurrentIteration] = value.ToOADate();
            }
            OnPropertyChanged("CurrentTime");
            OnPropertyChanged("CurrentYear");
            OnPropertyChanged("CurrentDayOfYear");
            OnPropertyChanged("CurrentHour");
            OnPropertyChanged("CurrentMinute");
            OnPropertyChanged("CurrentSecond");
        }
    }

    public int CurrentYear
    {
        get { return CurrentTime.Year; }
    }

    public int CurrentDayOfYear
    {
        get { return CurrentTime.DayOfYear; }
    }

    public int CurrentHour
    {
        get { return CurrentTime.Hour; }
    }

    public int CurrentMinute
    {
        get { return CurrentTime.Minute; }
    }

    public int CurrentSecond
    {
        get { return CurrentTime.Second; }
    }

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }
}
```

As seen above, I update various properties based on `CurrentIteration` and `CurrentTime`.

Also seen above in my MainWindow.xaml, I call a command when clicking a button in the ItemsControl. This command is located in the my MainViewModel which calls this function:

```
public void ShowTimeWindow(object parameter)
{
    var values = (object[])parameter;
    List<double> xValues = (List<double>)values[0];
    string winTitle = (string)values[2];

    Timeline newTimeLine = new Timeline(xValues);
    newTimeLine.DataContext = values[1]; //this is an item in the ItemsSource
    newTimeLine.Show();
}
```

So, the datacontext is set to an item in the ItemsSource. I've verified that the data is in there.

Here's the .xaml for the Timeline window:

```
<Window>
    <Grid>
        <TextBox IsReadOnly="True"
                 Text="{Binding CurrentYear,
                                Mode=OneWay}" />

        <TextBox IsReadOnly="True"
                 Text="{Binding CurrentDayOfYear,
                                Mode=OneWay}" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

When the values in the specified properties change, they are NOT updated correctly in the textboxes in the `Timeline` windows. They are being updated in the datacontext though as far as I can tell, using breakpoints and whatnot.

I'm out of ideas as to why it's not updating.

Edit: Here's how I'm updating the points (not the best way probably, I'm open to suggestions):

In my mainviewmodel:

```
public void SetData(int i) //i is just a constantly updated integer in my mainviewmodel
{
    foreach (VehicleModel vehicle in VehicleCollection)
    {
        vehicle.SetData(i);
    }
}
```

Then in my `VehicleMode.cs` class:

```
public void SetData(int i)
{
    CurrentIteration = i;
}
```

The above should in turn update the other properties that CurrentIteration notifies.

Comment: That `ShowTimeWindow` method makes it very difficult to guess what's going on. My guesses are a) maybe the Timeline window has `null` for a `DataContext`, or else b) it has a different copy of `VehicleModel` than the one you're changing elsewhere. If I were you, I would want the  actual parameter to `ShowTimeWindow` to be a class instance, that I'd cast once at the start of the method, and then I'd have named and typed properties to deal with.

Comment: So, the parameter for that method contains these three variables being passed in from within the `ItemsControl` as seen above:
`<Binding Path="NowTime" />
<Binding />
<Binding Path="Name" />`

So it should be passing in the `NowTime` list, the datacontext, and the `Name` property. I checked the assignment of `newTimeLine` and it's datacontext is assigned.

Comment: So you're saying to pass the `VehicleModel` instance itself as the parameter to `ShowTimeWindow`?

Comment: Ohhh, OK, that's why it's an array. But it looks to me like what you're passing is a) `DataContext.NowTime`, b) `DataContext`, c) `DataContext.Name` (and `DataContext` is `VehicleModel`). IOW, parameters 0 and 2 are just properties of parameter 1, so they're redundant. Though I can see how there might be cases where they're being pulled from some other object instead, in which case this would be the right way to do it.

Comment: You're correct, I guess I don't need the first two if I'm passing in the DataContext in the first place. Regardless, shouldn't the textboxes be updating properly?

Comment: Right, back from that tangent: First, what's `converter` doing on that multibinding? Is its `Convert` method just returning `values`? Does the Time window appear with the correct initial values for `CurrentYear` etc.?

Comment: Yes, it does appear with the correct initial values. When I set a breakpoint and look at the Time window's datacontext, I see that the values themselves are being updated properly. I'm going to add to the bottom of my post how they are being updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line in `VehicleViewModel.SetData()` is expected to update `CurrentTime`, which causes all the readonly properties to be "updated", by raising `PropertyChanged` for each of them.

```
CurrentIteration = i;
```

The setter in `CurrentTime` raises all those `PropertyChanged` notifications. But you never call that setter. The `CurrentIteration` setter just calls `OnPropertyChanged("CurrentTime")`.

Here's one quick fix. If it were me, I might do what's below, or I might be a little more inclined to make the `CurrentIteration` setter explicitly set `CurrentTime`. As a rule, if a property has a setter, *only* ever change it via the setter. I don't understand what you're doing well enough to write that one correctly, though.

```
protected void OnCurrentTimeChanged()
{
    OnPropertyChanged("CurrentTime");
    OnPropertyChanged("CurrentYear");
    OnPropertyChanged("CurrentDayOfYear");
    OnPropertyChanged("CurrentHour");
    OnPropertyChanged("CurrentMinute");
    OnPropertyChanged("CurrentSecond");
}

public DateTime CurrentTime
{
    get { return DateTime.FromOADate(NowTime[CurrentIteration]); }
    set
    {
        if ((value < FirstTime) || (value > LastTime))
        {
            CurrentTime = FirstTime;
        }
        else
        {
            NowTime[CurrentIteration] = value.ToOADate();
        }
        OnCurrentTimeChanged();
    }
}

private int _currentIteration;
public int CurrentIteration //used to hold current index of the list of data fields
{
    get { return _currentIteration; }
    set
    {
        _currentIteration = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("CurrentIteration");
        OnCurrentTimeChanged();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That did it. I was beating my head over this.